# Can a Workgroup name have embedded spaces, or should it be one word only?

Tags: windows-xp, workgroup

The workgroup here has two words, rather than the single word like `MSHOME`. Is there a problem with it having an embedded space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have Workgroup names with spaces, the only caveat is that machines older than Windows 2000, so ME, 98, 95 etc, will not support it and cannot join that work group. Also if you use a space, when it comes to using the workgroup name from the command line, you will need to enclose it in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Also be wary of any third-party software that may have been written with the assumption that there are no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Workgroup name originally didn't allow for spaces. Yes it **can** have spaces these days but it's certainly not recommended. Win2K and later will deal with it. Win9X will **mostly** deal with it but can be somewhat unpredictable. In most cases non-Windows machines will not be happy about it. Do yourself a favour and keep it as a single word, that way you will not need to worry about problems. As has already pointed out, software will be more hit and miss.